How should I parse times in the Japanese "30-hour" format for data analysis?
I'm considering a data analysis project involving information on Japanese TV broadcasts. The relevant data will include broadcast times, and some of those will be for programs that aired late at night.
Late-night Japanese TV schedules follow a non-standard time format called the 30-hour system (brief English explanation here). Most times are given in normal Japan Standard Time, formatted as %H:%M. Times from midnight to 6 AM, however, are treated as an extension of the previous day and numbered accordingly, under the logic that that's how people staying up late experience them. For example, Macross Frontier was broadcast in Kansai at 1:25 AM, but it was written as 25:25.
I want to use this data in a Pandas or Polars DataFrame. Theoretically, it could be left as a string, but it'd be more useful to convert it to a standard format for datetimes -- either Python's built-in type, or the types used in NumPy or Polars. One simple approach could be:
from datetime import date, time, datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

def process_30hour(d: date, t: str):
    h, m = [int(n) for n in t.split(':')] # assumes format 'HH:MM' for t
    if h > 23:
        h -= 24
        d += 1
    return datetime.combine(d, time(h, m), ZoneInfo('Japan'))

This could then be applied to a whole DataFrame with DataFrame.apply(). There may be a more performant way, however, especially considering the vectorization features of DataFrames -- both libraries recommend avoiding DataFrame.apply() if there's an alternative.

Could you provide a [mre] of the input dataframe?

Reading the strftime format specifier list, there is no option for 30 hour time. Therefore, I think that no vectorized option is possible.

IIUC, you could use create a datetime with '00:00' as time and add the hours as timedelta:
from datetime import date, time, datetime, timedelta
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

def process_30hour(d: date, t: str):
    h, m = map(int, t.split(':')) # assumes format 'HH:MM' for t
    return (datetime.combine(d, time(), ZoneInfo('Japan'))
           + timedelta(hours=h, minutes=m))

process_30hour(date(2024, 12, 20), '25:25')

Output:
datetime.datetime(2024, 12, 21, 1, 25, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='Japan'))

The same logic can be used vectorially with pandas:
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2024-12-20 20:25', '2024-12-20 25:25']})

# split string
tmp = df['date'].str.split(expand=True)

# convert to datetime/timedelta, combine
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(tmp[0]) + pd.to_timedelta(tmp[1]+':00')

For fun, as a one-liner:
df['datetime'] = (df['date'].add(':00')
                  .str.split(expand=True)
                  .astype({0: 'datetime64[ns]',
                           1: 'timedelta64[ns]'})
                  .sum(axis=1)
                 )

Output:
               date            datetime
0  2024-12-20 20:25 2024-12-20 20:25:00
1  2024-12-20 25:25 2024-12-21 01:25:00


Here is a pure Polars solution, using the same idea mentioned above of creating a date, then adding the hours/minutes of the 30-hour time.
df = pl.DataFrame({"date_string": ["2024-12-20 20:25", "2024-12-20 25:25"]})

date_split = pl.col("date_string").str.split_exact(" ", 1)
# assumes format 'HH:MM' for t
time_split = date_split.struct["field_1"].str.split_exact(":", 1)

df.with_columns(
    dt=(
        date_split.struct["field_0"].str.to_datetime()
        + pl.duration(
            hours=time_split.struct["field_0"],
            minutes=time_split.struct["field_1"],
        )
    ).dt.replace_time_zone("Japan")
)
# shape: (2, 2)
# ┌──────────────────┬─────────────────────────┐
# │ date_string      ┆ dt                      │
# │ ---              ┆ ---                     │
# │ str              ┆ datetime[μs, Japan]     │
# ╞══════════════════╪═════════════════════════╡
# │ 2024-12-20 20:25 ┆ 2024-12-20 20:25:00 JST │
# │ 2024-12-20 25:25 ┆ 2024-12-21 01:25:00 JST │
# └──────────────────┴─────────────────────────┘

This can be put into a function for abstraction / ease of re-use
def parse_30_hr_time(column: str | pl.Expr) -> pl.Expr:
    if isinstance(column, str):
        column = pl.col(column)
    
    date_split = column.str.split_exact(" ", 1)
    # assumes format 'HH:MM' for t
    time_split = date_split.struct["field_1"].str.split_exact(":", 1)

    return (
        date_split.struct["field_0"].str.to_datetime()
        + pl.duration(
            hours=time_split.struct["field_0"],
            minutes=time_split.struct["field_1"],
        )
    )

# same output as above
df.with_columns(dt=parse_30_hr_time("date_string").dt.replace_time_zone("Japan"))

As an alternative to ... + pl.duration(...), you can also use achieve the same result with Expr.dt.offset_by and pl.format
date_split.struct["field_0"].str.to_datetime()
# 20:25 -> 20h25m
.dt.offset_by(pl.format(
    "{}h{}m",
    time_split.struct["field_0"],
    time_split.struct["field_1"],
))

If your hour/minutes strings are in the format required by dt.offset_by, then things get a bit simpler too
# Note the 20h25m and 25h25m
df = pl.DataFrame({"date_string": ["2024-12-20 20h25m", "2024-12-20 25h25m"]})

date_split = pl.col("date_string").str.split_exact(" ", 1)

df.with_columns(
    dt=(
        date_split.struct["field_0"].str.to_datetime()
        .dt.offset_by(date_split.struct["field_1"])
        .dt.replace_time_zone("Japan")
    )
)

FWIW, there is also an accepted issue to introduce a duration string parser into Polars, which if/when completed would likely simplify this answer further,
